# String variable always appear empty in Golang template

Tags: javascript, html, go, go-templates

Can anybody explain why the string variable `{{.EndUpgradeTime }}` called in the `<script>` always appear to be an empty string in my browser inspect but it displays properly in the logs on Golang side?

Here is the template calling for the string:

```html
{{ define "content" }}

<h1>Your planet</h1>

<p class="lead">
Metal: {{ .MetalStock }} 
</p>

<img src="/static/images/planet.jpg" class="img-fluid pt-5" alt="planet image">

<div class="container mt-5">
<p>
Metal mine: level {{ .MetalMine }} (<a href="/planet/up_metal_mine">upgrade</a>)
</p>
</div>

<!-- Display the countdown timer in an element -->
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
// Set the date we're counting down to
var countDownDate = new Date({{ .EndUpgradeTime }}).getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

  // Get today's date and time
  var now = new Date().getTime();

  // Find the distance between now and the count down date
  var distance = countDownDate - now;

  // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

  // Display the result in the element with id="demo"
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h "
  + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

  // If the count down is finished, write some text
  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Done";
  }
}, 1000);
</script>

{{ end }}
```

Here is the struct I passed to execute the template:

```golang
type Planet struct {
    Id              int
    Uuid            string
    MetalStock      string
    MetalMine       string
    UserId          int
    CreatedAt       time.Time
    LastMetalUpdate time.Time
    EndUpgradeTime  string
}
```

Here are the methods setting the `EndUpgradeTime` string:

```golang
func (planet *Planet) UpgradeMine() {
    planet.EndUpgradeTime = "hello!"
    time.AfterFunc(planet.GetUpgradeTime(), planet.ApplyUpgrade)
    planet.EndUpgradeTime = time.Now().Add(planet.GetUpgradeTime()).Format("Mon Jan 02 2006 15:04:05 GMT-0700")
    fmt.Println("timer started")
    fmt.Println(planet.EndUpgradeTime)
}

func (planet *Planet) ApplyUpgrade() {
    planet.EndUpgradeTime = time.Time{}.Format("Mon Jan 02 2006 15:04:05 GMT-0700")
    fmt.Println("timer done")
    fmt.Println(planet.EndUpgradeTime)
    // update metal stock
    planet.GetMetalStock()
    // change metal level
    planet.UpMetalMine()
}
```

Here is the output in my terminal from Go, where you can see that the string is not empty since it's printing:
[image]

And here you can see that whatever I do, the string is still empty string within the script on the browser side:
[image]

What I want to do is a countdown timer that displays the time before completion of the upgrade when the metal actually is upgrading, but I can't find a good way to do that. If I only do the countdown on the client side, it will not work if the user refreshes or close the page and reopen it.

Thanks a lot!

PS: the handler calling the template

```golang
package main

import (
    "github.com/pdeguing/empire-and-foundation/data"
    "net/http"
)

// GET /dashboard
// Show player main dashboard page
func dashboard(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    sess, err := session(w, r)
    if err != nil {
        http.Redirect(w, r, "/login", 302)
        return
    }
    user, err := sess.User()
    if err != nil {
        info("cannot get user from session")
    }
    planet, err := data.PlanetByUserId(user.Id)
    if err != nil {
        info("could not get user planet", err)
        if planet, err = user.CreatePlanet(); err != nil {
            danger("could not create user planet:", err)
        }
    }
    newStock := planet.GetMetalStock()
    info("updated metal stock to :", newStock)
    generateHTML(w, planet, "layout", "private.navbar", "dashboard")
}
```

Comment: And how do you execute the template?

Comment: I send planet as data, the problem should not be in the execution since other variables are working fine in the template for the same object

Comment: And you're certain that neither `planet.GetMetalStock()` nor `planet.UpMetalMine()` unset the field?

Comment: Also please show how you're initializing/handling/modifying the `planet` instance all the way to the point where it is passed to `Execute` or `ExecuteTemplate`. For example how do we know that those methods that you've showed are called at the right time, just before the value is passed to the template? How do we know that you're passing a valid pointer and not a copy of the instance? How do we know that you, by mistake, aren't setting the field explicitly to an empty string just before passing it to the template.

Comment: ... for example this works https://play.golang.com/p/tpnsqXlBJ-9 it is a very much stripped down version of your code but it is clear that the field is set. What your logs show is *only* that the field is set at some point, but it does *not* show that it is set when passed to the template.

Comment: @mkopriva thank you, I should have follow chronological logic to find the problem. The page does not refresh itself when the string changes, and if I refresh it manually, it reloads planet from db to the struct. And since `EndUpgradeTime` was a test variable it does not exist in the db model so it does not get feed into the struct thus it appears as an empty string. Thank you!

Comment: I added the handler for you to see why you're right thanks again, I guess I just need to add the filed in db now.